# Virtual environment can't find a package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've created a virtual environment:

```
Filtrations-MacBook-Pro:test filter$ virtualenv cbase
Using base prefix '/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7'
New python executable in /Users/filter/Docs/tools/test/cbase/bin/python3.7
Also creating executable in /Users/filter/Docs/tools/test/cbase/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.
```

Okay, so now I will activate it like so:

```
Filtrations-MacBook-Pro:test filter$ source cbase/bin/activate
(cbase) Filtrations-MacBook-Pro:test filter$
```

As you can see, I am now using my virtual environment, so when I run `which` it will point to my vEnv:

```
(cbase) Filtrations-MacBook-Pro:test filter$ which python
/Users/filter/Docs/tools/test/cbase/bin/python
(cbase) Filtrations-MacBook-Pro:test filter$ which pip
/Users/filter/Docs/tools/test/cbase/bin/pip
(cbase) Filtrations-MacBook-Pro:test filter$
```

The versions pip and python are using:

```
(cbase) Filtrations-MacBook-Pro:test filter$ pip -V
pip 20.0.1 from /Users/filter/Docs/tools/test/cbase/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
(cbase) Filtrations-MacBook-Pro:test filter$ python -V
Python 3.7.6
(cbase) Filtrations-MacBook-Pro:test filter$
```

Now I install coinbase(https://pypi.org/project/coinbase/):

```
(cbase) Filtrations-MacBook-Pro:test filter$ pip install coinbase
Processing /Users/filter/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/9c/bd/d2/0deea345cde4f6a31d8165c0e83789bf2c836cfc1d7898300d/coinbase-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pycryptodome>=3.4.11
  Using cached pycryptodome-3.9.4-cp37-cp37m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (10.1 MB)
Collecting requests>=2.5
  Using cached requests-2.22.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
Collecting six>=1.9
  Using cached six-1.14.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17
  Using cached certifi-2019.11.28-py2.py3-none-any.whl (156 kB)
Collecting idna<2.9,>=2.5
  Using cached idna-2.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Collecting chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1
  Using cached urllib3-1.25.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
Installing collected packages: pycryptodome, certifi, idna, chardet, urllib3, requests, six, coinbase
Successfully installed certifi-2019.11.28 chardet-3.0.4 coinbase-2.1.0 idna-2.8 pycryptodome-3.9.4 requests-2.22.0 six-1.14.0 urllib3-1.25.8
(cbase) Filtrations-MacBook-Pro:test filter$ pip list
Package      Version   
------------ ----------
certifi      2019.11.28
chardet      3.0.4     
coinbase     2.1.0     
idna         2.8       
pip          20.0.1    
pycryptodome 3.9.4     
requests     2.22.0    
setuptools   45.1.0    
six          1.14.0    
urllib3      1.25.8    
wheel        0.33.6    
(cbase) Filtrations-MacBook-Pro:test filter$
```

Okay, it seemed to install corectly, but when I try and run it with python:

```
(cbase) Filtrations-MacBook-Pro:test filter$ python -i
Python 3.7.6 (default, Dec 30 2019, 19:38:26) 
[Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from coinbase.wallet.client import Client
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/filter/Docs/tools/test/coinbase.py", line 1, in <module>
    from coinbase.wallet.client import Client
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'coinbase.wallet'; 'coinbase' is not a package
>>>
```

But if I ls my site-packages folder, its there in it's glory:

```
(cbase) Filtrations-MacBook-Pro:test filter$ ls cbase/lib/python3.7/site-packages/
Crypto              chardet-3.0.4.dist-info     idna-2.8.dist-info      requests            six.py
__pycache__         coinbase            pip             requests-2.22.0.dist-info   urllib3
certifi             coinbase-2.1.0.dist-info    pip-20.0.1.dist-info        setuptools          urllib3-1.25.8.dist-info
certifi-2019.11.28.dist-info    easy_install.py         pkg_resources           setuptools-45.1.0.dist-info wheel
chardet             idna                pycryptodome-3.9.4.dist-info    six-1.14.0.dist-info        wheel-0.33.6.dist-info
```

`type -a Python` returns the following if it's of any help:

```
(cbase) Filtrations-MacBook-Pro:test filter$ type -a python
python is /Users/filter/Docs/tools/test/cbase/bin/python
python is /usr/local/bin/python
python is /usr/bin/python
```

I am at a loss, any help would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete your local coinbase.py in your test folder or run python in a different folder

Comment: Interesting when I renamed coinbase.py to something else it worked, can't I have my .py files as the same name as a pip module?

Comment: @Filtration _can't I have my .py files as the same name as a pip module?_ I don't believe so, no. I hope miholeus edits their answer to provide some sort of explanation, at least.